# Stretching a UIImage across the length of a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

What I basically need to achieve is a Fruit Ninja - style "slash" effect, where the "slash" trails the user's touch and follows the shape of the user's gesture, and is thinner the longer the distance the user has swiped.

The simplest way to achieve this seemed to be to collect all the points the user passes through in a UIBezierPath, and "stretch" an image through the length of the BezierPath. This would achieve the kind of "trailing" effect I was looking for and also ensure that the line is thinner if the distance travelled is longer.

However I can't seem to find a way to actually implement this. Is this even possible?

Alternatives? Thanks.

P.S: This is for a low-medium priority section of a regular app and not a game, so I would like to avoid having go down to OpenGL and spend a lot of time to achieve this (with completely custom drawing, etc). Something at the SDK level would be preferred, and if that's not possible at all, we'll just figure out a different UI.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say more about the effect you want to acheive? Some alternative graphics would be great.

Comment: https://lh6.ggpht.com/xmvuGIyF1egkKN8jdbMHJ5SheCe2Tc2KXV86bU5-GWPGrU16xhQwjMF2MDdynkRcFkcr=h230 Fruit Ninja is the best example. Notice the "slashing" effect which basically looks like a bitmap that is stretched, or something drawn completely custom. It follows the curve of the user's "slash" gesture (even if it's a circular one) and stretches thin over the course of a longer gesture. But I guess there's no "easy" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For pretty easy-to-use stretching teqhniques of images/views you could look into

https://github.com/hfossli/AGGeometryKit/

Comment: Nice, I guess I could apply a bunch of transforms to the image and update the transform as per the touch direction and velocity. But I would also like to be able to follow the curve of the user's gesture and draw/stretch the image "along" that curved path. I don't know if that's possible. :)

Comment: Yes, I don't think that is possible like you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to draw using CoreGraphics. See this link

http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2011/12/02/how-to-build-a-simple-painting-app-for-ios/

Comment: I think I may have to stick to this. Unless the Fruit Ninja screenshot I provided inspires any other ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Maybe you can use this.

https://github.com/hfossli/AGDraw

Just something I wrote a while ago. Hit clear and try to draw something (clear will toggle between two types of strokes). You'll see the width of the penstroke will increase with the velocity you use.. I guess that fits your need. If you fix some bugs, please make a pull request. You are free to use the code, but I will add a MIT license later.

Comment: Sure thing, will check it out. Thanks. AND mark one of these answers as accepted depending on which approach I finalise!